# Flow type: either one property is required or the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to define a type in flow such that you must specify *either* a Client or an Invoice. This is my attempt at doing that:

```
type Client = {
  client: {
    id: number,
  },
  invoice?: {
    id: number,
  },
};

type Invoice = { 
  client?: {
    id: number,
  },
  invoice: {
    id: number,
  },
};

type Props = Client | Invoice;
```

If *client* is undefined, then *invoice* must be defined and vice-versa.

However, when I try to access properties based on this, the flow typechecker throws errors:

```
function getAssignedId({client, invoice}: Props) {
  return client ? client.id : invoice.id;
}
```

results in:

```
22:   return client ? client.id : invoice.id;
                                          ^ Cannot get `invoice.id` because property `id` is missing in undefined [1].
References:
21: function getAssignedId({client, invoice}: Asssignement) {
                                    ^ [1]
```

[You can try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSwgO2FAvFA3gHwFBRQDUAxoisAFzYGHEIAm1yArgLYBGEATgDS0BffoSIJkANwD2CEhAD81LLRGNm7Ln0H8cAgNx48oSFACSE6bIzYcUWqXKoFNOvSZRWnHsKhC7YqTIQisquap6ahL46+obg0ACCAM7JCADmyBBsFFbwSKhQNmYBsjEAZizIJMAIkshQqRDASYlpGQwmDAAUWGR5wLxQ-hYQAtTNLemZFACUzlDcjSzcdb3ZclCrqAB0jFDUQ4E7DPoCQA).

Any idea why this is happening? Is there another way to achieve this with flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do deconstruct the type via:

```
{client, invoice}: Props
```

the types of those variables are resolved. `client` and `invoice` both are resolved as `?{ id: number }` since they may or may not exist at the time. The typechecker does not remember that these two objects are linked, because you have separated them.

If you don't separate them, flow can keep track of the union type and do the right thing.

```
function getAssignedId(obj: Props) {
  return obj.client ? obj.client.id : obj.invoice.id;
}
```

[Try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSwgO2FAvFA3gKClAY0RWAC5s98oEATc5AVwFsAjCAJwBpKBfb-BMgBuAewQEIAfnK4q1OlEasO-KHxw8A3DhyhIUAJLCxEjNiiUiSVNIpza9Zmy69Vg0eIgzKAhUueq6lo6etAACuwiYADOZvDWaAA+hsae2jgAZgzIBMAIIshQAOYQwACC0dEIRcgQNAY0ABQiLABW5BFR0QCUdlDspQzshS2tAHRWJFCSUKMTxKhjtFDkc+4mEEs02jxAA)

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if invoice is defined. If you add the check it will not throw the error